# All bluetooth audio devices not showing in sound settings Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: drivers, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, pipewire

### The Problem

I recently installed Ubuntu 21.10 I proceeded to install [EasyEffects](https://github.com/wwmm/easyeffects).

(disclaimer: I don't know a lot about ubuntus/linux audio device management, please excuse noob questions here)

Unfortunately I might have broken something in the process of doing so. Any hardware attached Audio device is showing up perfectly fine, Including the builtin ones and hdmi audio sinks. They are fully functional.

Initially I couldn't connect to any bluetooth audio device. After manually executing `pulseaudio --start` i was able to connect to the devices, but since pulseaudio and specifically it's bluetooth module seem to be "deprecated" with the bluetooth module being explicitly deprecated, i'm not sure if that is helpful or might even cause problems in the end.

### What i've tried (non-exhaustive list)

I found a few threads from around 16.04 times when searching for these problems and tried quite a few solutions, but most seem outdated since most involve pulseaudio and as far as i'm aware i shouldn't be using pulse at the moment.

The following is a short list of things i tried:

- Tried uninstalling pulseaudio -> unsuccessful as it would've uninstalled gdm and ubuntu-gnome-desktop for some reason
- Reinstall pipewire, pipewire-pulse -> no effect
- Manually make sure pulseaudio is not running -> no effect
- tried loading pactl module-bluetooth-discover -> not sure if that's even relevant since it's pulseaudio but this does fail:

```
❯ sudo -H pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
Connection failure: Connection refused
pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused
```

(honestly copied this without knowing too much about it)

- uninstalled EasyEffects flatpak -> no effect
- connect using a2dp.py script -> fails with

```
Cannot find `bluez_card.MAC_OF_MY_BT_Head_device` using `pactl list cards short`. Retrying 15 more times
```

it just does that until it reaches 0 my hopes were already low since it says it's for 16.04

- checked if bluez is installed -> it is
- checked for any system updates
- checked for "additional drivers" using Software&update
- rebooted multiple times

### Additional Info:

pactl list modules short output (not sure if relevant?)

```
❯ pactl list modules short
1   libpipewire-module-rt   {
            nice.level    = -11
            #rt.prio      = 88
            #rt.time.soft = -1
            #rt.time.hard = -1
        }   
2   libpipewire-module-protocol-native      
3   libpipewire-module-profiler     
5   libpipewire-module-metadata     
7   libpipewire-module-spa-device-factory       
9   libpipewire-module-spa-node-factory     
11  libpipewire-module-client-node      
13  libpipewire-module-client-device        
15  libpipewire-module-portal       
16  libpipewire-module-access   {
            # access.allowed to list an array of paths of allowed
            # apps.
            #access.allowed = [
            #    /usr/bin/pipewire-media-session
            #]

            # An array of rejected paths.
            #access.rejected = [ ]

            # An array of paths with restricted access.
            #access.restricted = [ ]

            # Anything not in the above lists gets assigned the
            # access.force permission.
            #access.force = flatpak
        }   
17  libpipewire-module-adapter      
19  libpipewire-module-link-factory     
21  libpipewire-module-session-manager      
536870912   module-always-sink      
536870913   module-switch-on-connect
```

[headphones connected as headset device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXr1p.png)

[Headphones not showing up as sink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wR0B.png)

If i should add any additional information i will happily do so, any pointer where to look would be appreciated.

The device is clearly registered as an audio device with alsa.

```
❯ sudo bluealsa-aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Bluetooth Devices ****
hci0: 14:3F:A6:E4:9C:C1 [WF-1000XM4], trusted audio-card
  SCO (CVSD): S16_LE 1 channel 8000 Hz
  A2DP (LDAC): S16_LE 2 channels 96000 Hz
**** List of CAPTURE Bluetooth Devices ****
hci0: 14:3F:A6:E4:9C:C1 [WF-1000XM4], trusted audio-card
  SCO (CVSD): S16_LE 1 channel 8000 Hz
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing some modules. Try running this and see if it works:

```
sudo apt install gstreamer1.0-pipewire libpipewire-0.3-{0,dev,modules} libspa-0.2-{bluetooth,dev,jack,modules} pipewire{,-{audio-client-libraries,pulse,bin,locales,tests}}
```

If not, you might also want to try to reinstall pipewire upstream using its ppa. Details on that :

https://pipewire-debian.github.io/pipewire-debian/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions. I tried installing those dependencies, while it did install something there, still no luck with any of my BT audio devices.
Then i tried following the instructions on the Link, that didn't work either. 
Considering to just reinstall Ubuntu if i can't resolve this. But thanks for your help anyway!